# node.js on intel-galileo with windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, intel-galileo, windowsondevices

Has anyone successfully used node.js on an intel-galileo device with windows? I tried running the executable, but that alone didn't provide the node.js environment in the command line as it does when run from the command line on the desktop. Are there certain Windows APIs that are not available, thus node.js fails?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this question for months.  I held off working with the Galileo until Microsoft released their min win version.  I have tried and failed to install Node.js several times on the min win version for Intel Galileo.  I finally started using the Intel XDK image, it works great using the mraa library to control the GPIO, but it would be nice if the good folks at Microsoft or Intel could give us a definitive answer to this.  Seems there are more questions than answers anywhere you look. Good luck.